# Reading multiple text files into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, text-files

I am writing a program that opens numerous text files and reads from them parameters for planetary bodies. I have a problem when reading the text files.

**sample text file**

```
 2
 1, 1, 2
 3.5, 3, 4
```

The first number (2) refers to the number of bodies found in the file. The next 2 lines correspond to the planet's parameters (x and y coordinates and mass respectively). I have 4 text files containing different amounts of bodies and need to store all the data in a variable.

**my code**

```
struct body {

float x;
float y;
float mass;

};

int main()
{

struct body b[8];
FILE *fp;
int i, j, k;
int num, count = 0;
char fName[10];

for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)    
{ 
    sprintf(fName,"bodies%d.txt",i);
    fp = fopen(fName, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {   
        printf("Can't open %s \n",fName);
        exit(-1);
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &num);


    for (j = count; j < num; j++)
    {               
        fscanf(fp, "%f%*c %f%*c %f%*c", &b[j].x, &b[j].y, &b[j].mass);
        printf("%f %f %f\n", b[j].x, b[j].y, b[j].mass);

        count = j;
    }               


}
```

It is reading the numbers from the text files, but it is stopping after 6 readings and there are 8 in total.

What could be the problem?

Comment: `sprintf(fName,"bodies%d.txt",i);` <-- Buffer overflow. `fName` can hold a maximum of 9 `char`s +1 for `\0` at the end. You copy 12 `char`s into it(`\0` included). Why do you have `count`?

Comment: `count` refers to the next position of the array

Comment: That's confusing and wrong. Think. When you do `j = count`, you check `j < num` . That's wrong. Use `j=0` instead of `j = count` and it is better to use `count++` instead of `count=j`. And in the loop, instead of `b[j]`, use `b[count]`. And I don't like your way of hardcoding arrays(unless you know the number of bodies in each file beforehand).

Comment: suggest refactor functionality to a function eg. `struct body *read_body(FILE *fp)`. and minimise your problem to one single call to this function

Comment: I understood the problem, very stupid mistake in fact. Corrected the loop, thanks! They are hardcoded because I already know the number of bodies in each file beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code has some problems**:

1. `fName` is declared as

   ```
   char fName[10];
   ```

   and you use

   ```
   sprintf(fName,"bodies%d.txt",i);
   ```

   which writes 12 characters into `fName`(including the NUL-terminator) which can atmost hold 9 characters(+1 for the NUL-terminator).
2. The `for` loop:

   ```
   for (j = count; j < num; j++)
   {               
       fscanf(fp, "%f%*c %f%*c %f%*c", &b[j].x, &b[j].y, &b[j].mass);
       printf("%f %f %f\n", b[j].x, b[j].y, b[j].mass);

       count = j;
   }
   ```

   has many problems and is confusing too. When you do `j = count`, you check `j < num`. This makes no sense as `count` is not related to `num`.

**Fixes**:

1. For the first problem, allocate enough space for `fName`:

   ```
   char fName[12];
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   char fName[10];
   ```
2. As for the second problem, use

   ```
   for (j = 0; j < num; j++) //j should be initialized to 0
   {               
       fscanf(fp, "%f%*c %f%*c %f%*c", &b[count].x, &b[count].y, &b[count].mass);
       printf("%f %f %f\n", b[count].x, b[count].y, b[count].mass); //Use b[count] instead of b[j]

       //count = j; Works, but the below is better
       count++;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `j = count` with `j = 0` in the second `for` loop.